# Div block after clicked item's row (responsive)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of products that, when clicked, shows an inline 'popup' that  contains more information of the clicked list item.

Now the thing is that this list is also responsive, so on desktop this list would be 4 columns, tablet 3 columns, mobile 2 columns etc.

I know I can use jquery to count these list items and determine after which 'nth' item this 'popup' block needs to be displayed, but how would I achieve this when resizing the browser?

I have set up an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz1wyqm3/90/).

```
$(".products li").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(".products li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".popup-holder").after( $(".product-popup") );

  var i = $(this).index();
  var r = 4;

  do {
    if ( i > r ) {
      r += 4;
      if ( i == r) {
        r += 4;
      }
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  while ( i != r );

  $(".products li:nth-child("+i+")").after( $(".product-popup") );
  $(".product-popup").show();
  $(".product-popup span").text(i);

});
```

**Underneath a visual example of what I am trying to achieve:**

[image: Product list]

After clicking a list item, the popup displays after the 4th item:

[image: Product clicked displaying popup]

After resizing the browser, the 'popup' should display after the 3rd item:

[image: List view after resizing to tablet]

Comment: [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) allows you to easily check which media queries currently apply.

Comment: find screen width and set modal after for that particular div.. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think about this differently. The idea is to first add margin-bottom to current element to create the needed space, then add the element below it using absolute position and we calculate the top position using the current element clicked.

Here is a very simplified example that you can elaborate more to make the calculation more accurate considering different parametres (dynamic content, dynamic height, etc).

```js
$(".products li").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(".products li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var i = $(this).data('information');

  var top = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
  $(".product-popup").css('top',top + 30);
  
  $(".product-popup").text(i);
  $(".product-popup").show();
  
});
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if($(".active").length) {
    var top = $(".active").position().top + $(".active").height();
    $(".product-popup").css('top',top + 30);
  }
};
```

```css
ul.products {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

ul.products li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20.66666%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.products li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

ul.products li.active {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom:80px;
}

.product-popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  left:5px;
  right:0;
  
}
.container {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<ul class="products">
  <li data-information="More information 1">Example product 1</li>
  <li data-information="More information 2">Example product 2</li>
  <li data-information="More information 3">Example product 3</li>
  <li data-information="More information 4">Example product 4</li>
  <li data-information="More information 5">Example product 5</li>
  <li data-information="More information 6">Example product 6</li>
  <li data-information="More information 7">Example product 7</li>
  <li data-information="More information 8">Example product 8</li>
  <li data-information="More information 9">Example product 9</li>
  <li data-information="More information 10">Example product 10</li>
  <li data-information="More information 11">Example product 11</li>
  <li data-information="More information 12">Example product 12</li>
</ul>
<div class="popup-holder">
  <div class="product-popup"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a demo with dynamic content:

```js
$(".products li").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(".products li").removeClass("active").css('margin-bottom',5);
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var i = $(this).data('information');

  var top = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
  $(".product-popup").css('top',top + 30);
  
  $(".product-popup").text(i);
  $(this).css('margin-bottom',$(".product-popup").outerHeight());
  $(".product-popup").show();
  
});
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if($(".active").length) {
    var top = $(".active").position().top + $(".active").height();
    $(".product-popup").css('top',top + 30);
    $(".active").css('margin-bottom',$(".product-popup").outerHeight());
  }
};
```

```css
ul.products {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

ul.products li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20.66666%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.products li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

ul.products li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.product-popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  right:0;
  
}
.container {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<ul class="products">
  <li data-information="lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume">Example product 1</li>
  <li data-information="More information 2">Example product 2</li>
  <li data-information="More information 3">Example product 3</li>
  <li data-information="lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume">Example product 4</li>
  <li data-information="More information 5">Example product 5</li>
  <li data-information="More information 6">Example product 6</li>
  <li data-information="More information 7">Example product 7</li>
  <li data-information="More information 8">Example product 8</li>
  <li data-information="lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume lorem ipsume">Example product 9</li>
  <li data-information="More information 10">Example product 10</li>
  <li data-information="More information 11">Example product 11</li>
  <li data-information="More information 12">Example product 12</li>
</ul>
<div class="popup-holder">
  <div class="product-popup"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: this won't work if we select the item and resize the browser.

Comment: @DeepuReghunath i know, because i said `it  a very simplifed example` ;) i only share the basic idea.

Comment: @DeepuReghunath well i added two more line of code to adjust on window resize if you want ;)

Comment: I really like your clean way of doing it! The only issue now is that the popup will have a variable height depending on the amount of information. Is this solution possible while keeping the popup responsive instead of a fixed height?

Comment: @Pascal yes sure ;) as you can see, the height of the popup is somehow equal to the margin-bottom i added to active class ... so the idea is to keep height auto and calculate the margin-bottom equal to height ;) you can easily do this

Comment: @Pascal i added another example with dynamic content ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That works perfect! I've only changed the offset() with position(), so it would only take the distance from the container into consideration instead of the browser.

Comment: @Pascal ok great ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have done with the position of next element. When you resize the browser also it will work.

```js
var cIt=null;
$(".products li").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  cIt=$(this);
  showDetails($(this));
  
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    if(cIt!=null)
      showDetails(cIt);
};
function showDetails(item){

  $(".products li").removeClass("active");
  item.addClass("active");
  $(".popup-holder").after( $(".product-popup") );

   var i = item.index() +1;

  var elem=item;
  

  while(elem.next().position().top==elem.position().top)
  {
   elem=elem.next();
  }
  elem.after( $(".product-popup") );
  $(".product-popup").show();
  $(".product-popup span").text(i);
}
```

```css
ul.products {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.products li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2% 10px 0;
  width: 20.66666%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.products li:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  margin: 0 0 1% 0;
}
ul.products li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul.products li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.product-popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products">
<li data-information="More information 1">Example product 1</li><li data-information="More information 2">Example product 2</li><li data-information="More information 3">Example product 3</li><li data-information="More information 4">Example product 4</li>
<li data-information="More information 5">Example product 5</li><li data-information="More information 6">Example product 6</li><li data-information="More information 7">Example product 7</li><li data-information="More information 8">Example product 8</li><li data-information="More information 9">Example product 9</li><li data-information="More information 10">Example product 10</li><li data-information="More information 11">Example product 11</li><li data-information="More information 12">Example product 12</li>
</ul>

<div class="popup-holder">
  <div class="product-popup">More information (i = <span>0</span>)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea considering performance to re-call the whole function on resize ..

Comment: This answer seems to be doing what I initially looked for! Could it be improved by changing the way it re-calls the whole function like @TemaniAfif mentioned?